Embed an object and display as icon in ppt using vba
I am trying to automate the metrics I generate. I've automated the data manipulation in excel and I've automated the copying the charts over to PowerPoint. Now I'm trying to automate the embedding of documents at the end of the powerpoint. We embed 4 documents as icons. I might include code to delete the old icons, but for now I just want to get them on the ppt. Here's my code so far: I've modified the code a bit.
dim ppt_app as new powerpoint.application
dim mypres as powerpoint.presentation, myslide as powerpoint.slide
dim osh as powerpoint.shape
code to get month, year and day

I use the dates to set workbooks and ppts as those are in the file names
code to set different date iterations like yyyymmdd, yyyy_mm_dd, etc.
set mypres = ppt_app.Presentation("string1" & dtvariable & ".pptx")
n= mypres.slides.count
set myslides = mypres.slides(n-1) 'slide to embed the documents

fpath = "string for central loc"
v1 = "string1" & dtvariable & ".pdf"
v2 = "string2" & dtvariable & ".xlsx"

myslides.shapes.addOLEobject (filename:=fpath & v1, link:=msofalse, displayasicon:=msotrue, iconlabel:=v1, iconindex:=5, confiliename:="C:\Windows\Installer\{90160000-000F-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}\xlicons.exe" 

I will change index to 1 when I put code to delete the icons
with osh
    .Left = 2.29 * 72
    .Top = 2.49 * 72
    .Height = 0.84 * 72
    .Width = 1 * 72
End With

I tried using other questions and followed those examples and tried to match my code, but I still can't get it to quite work. I got it work some as it would show the first page of the pdf document, but obviously that's not what I'm trying to do. Thanks.

Error is run-time error '-214767259 (80004005) Method 'AddOLEObject' of object 'Shapes' failed

Missing  an argument for IconFileName  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.addoleobject#:~:text=as%20an%20icon.-,IconFileName,-Optional

@TimWilliams i thought that was optional, due it saying optional and none of the examples showed to use to the icon install file when embedding files.

IconFileName is optional, but you need to include it if you supply an argument to iconindex or IconLabel.

thanks. I saw that somewhere. I've added the icon file name by clicking on browse and when the change icon pops up when inserting an object and I get the same error.  Is the beginning addoleobject and myslides.shapes correct. because that seems to be where the error is pointing, but it looks like it matches several examples i've found.

What type of file are you supplying to IconFileName ?

an .exe file. I did a record macro in excel and it used the icon "wordicon.exe", so I figured ppt would be similar. I've added the code I used for the installer.  The default windows location shows a graph.ico file unselected and there's a filename in the filename called xlicons.ico. But the excel document didn't use the .ico, but .exe, so I switched to all files and chose the .exe version.

Typo in your edit version: confiliename

This works for me:
Sub Tester()
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
        .Shapes.AddOLEObject Top:=100, Left:=100, _
                     FileName:="C:\Temp\logo.png", _
                     DisplayAsIcon:=msoTrue, _
                     link:=msoFalse, _
                     iconfilename:="C:\Temp\icon.ico", _
                     iconindex:=0, _
                     iconlabel:="Test"
    End With
End Sub


I think I tried something similar to that, but I think without the with statement. I will try it like that.

The With is just there for appearance - you can make it all one line and it still works the same.

so i tried that and got a class not registered. I went back through my code and found an error with a filestring not having an extenstion. I added the .csv extension with the xlicons.exe icon install file and it loaded it up. But it didn't work when I tested it with another excel file, which did have ane xtension.

myslide.Shapes.AddOLEObject Filename:=fpath & v1, link:=msoFalse, Displayasicon:=msoTrue, Iconlabel:=summ, IconIndex:=1, IconFileName:="C:\Windows\Installer\{90160000-000F-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}\xlicons.exe"

This was the set of code that created the objects, but the problem wasn't this. I had some errors in the file names the code was trying to access, like incorrect extension or missing some other separator in the dates of the file name. The only thing I don't understand is why the icon installer was using 2 different icons when it was using the same icon with this path: "C:\Windows\Installer{90160000-000F-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}\xlicons.exe". That's the one thing I don't understand.
